# How can assign data of excel to db table column after reordered excel column by dragAndDrop using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have two movable `gridView` by `dragAndDrop`. `GridView1` for DB table column name and `GridView2` for excel column name. When I upload excel a popup first shows excel column from sheet and DB table column name. And both `gridViews`  are movable by `dragAndDrop`. Here we map excel column with DB table column:

```
protected void sheetNameddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    List<string> sheetNames = new List<string>();
    sheetNames = (List<string>)ViewState["sheetName"];
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    foreach (string sheetName in sheetNames)
    {
        string compare = Regex.Replace(sheetName, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+", "");
        string con = (string)ViewState["conString"];
        if (compare == sheetNameddl.SelectedValue)
        {
            string sqlQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
            OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, con);
            oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(ds);                

            List<object> list = new List<object>();                                     
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                ViewState["DataTable"] = table;
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {

                    list.Add(new { column.ColumnName });
                }
            }
            GridView2.DataSource = list;
            GridView2.DataBind();
            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

        }
    }
}

protected void ddltablename_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Odisha1ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_Name='Customer' order by ORDINAL_POSITION", conn);

    conn.Open();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView3.DataSource = dt;
    GridView3.DataBind();
    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    conn.Close();
}  

    // for gidView
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: initial">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="0"  OnRowDataBound="GridView3_RowDataBound" ForeColor="#333" runat="server">
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#989898" ForeColor="white" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
        <td class="clear col-2" style="vertical-align: initial">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2"  CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="0"  OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" ForeColor="#333" runat="server">               
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#989898" ForeColor="white" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="Footer" >
    <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnsave_Click" />
</div>

// for drag and drop
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=GridView2]").sortable({
            items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            axis: 'y',
            dropOnEmpty: false,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.addClass("selected");
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.removeClass("selected");
            },
            receive: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
            }
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=GridView3]").sortable({
            items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            axis: 'y',
            dropOnEmpty: false,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.addClass("selected");
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.removeClass("selected");
            },
            receive: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using this code, I am able to move `gridview` column but unable to change the order of index using `dragANdDrop`.

Now I want to change the order of `gridview` rows and map column using row index. I want this for if excel column name is different then data of excel column is saved at right db table column.

If excel column row index is same as db column index then data of that excel column will save in same row index column of db.

Here `GridView1` for DB table column name and `GridView2` for excel column name as said above. Please give me any idea to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.